# File extracted on windows and then copied to linux - any issue in file format on LINUX

Tags: linux, windows, zip, unzip

Wanted to understand if a zip file is extracted on windows and then extracted files are copied (WINSCP) to LINUX machine.

l there be any issue on Linux related to file format ?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Seems a bit as if you suspected this to be a problem but for whatever reason you don't verify that...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

scp does not transform the file in any way; there is no difference between extracting the file on one system and transferring it to the destination system via scp versus extracting the file directly on the destination system (assuming no transfer errors occur).